# using pandas.to_csv(df) only displays a subset of numpy.array in Excel

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, pandas

I have a `pandas.DataFrame` with 2 columns. The first column is a simple integer, the second column is a `numpy.array` of length 50. I want to write these two columns into a CSV file, but when I use `.to_csv()` and open the file in Excel, only a subset of the values appear and are accessible. The length is variable and I seem to be getting a column of same string length (more or less) when I open it in Excel. 
Does pandas.to_csv() write some sort of visual interpretation to file, not the actual data in the `DataFrame` ?

How can I write this to CSV properly so that I can use it in Excel?

Comment: I think that's a display issue on Excel's part. Can you check the file with a text editor?

Comment: Argl... @ayhan you are right! Is it best for me to delete this question? Or rephrase it?

Comment: If you think the question can be helpful for someone else in the future, I think you don't need to delete it. If you think it would be more helpful, you can rephrase it too. It's up to you. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that `50` values of second column are in one cell in `Excel` for each row.

I think you can create with `numpy array` column new columns by [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.apply.html) `Series` and then [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) first column `a`. Last write [`to_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [0,1,5], 'b': [np.arange(50), np.arange(50), np.arange(50)]} )
print df
   a                                                  b
0  0  [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13,...
1  1  [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13,...
2  5  [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13,...    

print df.b.apply(pd.Series)
   0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  ...  40  41  42  43  44  45  46  47  \
0   0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9 ...  40  41  42  43  44  45  46  47   
1   0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9 ...  40  41  42  43  44  45  46  47   
2   0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9 ...  40  41  42  43  44  45  46  47   

   48  49  
0  48  49  
1  48  49  
2  48  49  

df = pd.concat([df['a'], df.b.apply(pd.Series)], axis=1)
print df
[3 rows x 50 columns]
   a  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8 ...  40  41  42  43  44  45  46  47  48  49
0  0  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8 ...  40  41  42  43  44  45  46  47  48  49
1  1  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8 ...  40  41  42  43  44  45  46  47  48  49
2  5  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8 ...  40  41  42  43  44  45  46  47  48  49
```

```
#for testing
print df.to_csv()
#write to file
#print df.to_csv('filename')

,a,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49
0,0,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49
1,1,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49
2,5,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49
```

EDIT:

If you need write `DataFrame` [`to_excel`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html):

```
#write to excel, omit index of DataFrame
df.to_excel('test.xlsx', index=False)
```

Comment: Thanks this works! but as @ayhan mentioned, this is actually more of an excel problem. Is it better for me to rephrase this or simply delete the question?

Comment: I think you can rephrase question.

Comment: Ok, you need write `DataFrame` to excel? Because you can or create csv  (.csv) or create excel file (.xlxs).

Comment: yeah, I basically just need to store some data for my colleagues in an easily accessible format. What you suggest works for me. It basically splits the array up, and doesn't store it in 2 columns, but at @ayhan mentioned, this is a problem with Excel. But as most people use Excel, I guess I have to conform...

Comment: Ok, I give code for writing to excel. If you dont need write index, add `index=False`.

Comment: One question - there are always data in second column with `length = 50` ?

Comment: That's neat! And in this case yes, but in general in my case no, that's why I wanted to keep it as 2 columns instead of 51 columns.

Comment: Ok. Because if there are different length, you get `NaN` values in last columns - test it `df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [0,1,5], 'b': [np.arange(50), np.arange(50), np.arange(45)]} )` (last 50 changed to 45) . Then you can use [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html).

Comment: Thank you for accepting. You can upvote too - click to small triangle above `0` above accepting mark. Thanks.